# '#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command when executing awk script

Tags: windows, awk, cmd

Following the tutorial https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html
i created a cmd file on windows that have a simple awk script

```
 #! /bin/awk -f

BEGIN { print "Don't Panic!" }
```

However windows doesn't accept the Shebang notation #! and throws me an error:

> '#!' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

How can i make the file executable on windows cmd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "shebang" (sharp+bang) notation `#!` is very specifically a Unix/Linux kernel thing; when you use the `exec(2)` system call to execute a file, there's logic that will look to see if the file is a script and, if so, invoke the specified interpreter on it, instead of just expecting the file itself to be an executable binary. I don't think there's any analogous way to turn a script with an arbitrary interpreter into a directly-executable command on Windows using `CMD`.

What you can do is pick a file suffix (like `.awk`), associate that suffix with the awk executable in Explorer, and then use `start` (or double-clicking) to run awk scripts instead of just typing the bare filename.

But you want to turn an awk script into a command that you can run at the CMD prompt, the most reliable way would be to make a batch (`.bat`) file that runs awk on the file manually, which looks something like this (assuming the awk script file is in the same folder as the batch file):

```
@echo off
awk -f "%~dp0filename.awk"
```

Here's a working example built from your script:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
c:\users\mjreed\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;...

C:\>type \users\mjreed\bin\hello.bat
@echo off
awk -f "%~dp0hello.awk"

C:\>type \users\mjreed\bin\hello.awk
BEGIN { print "Don't Panic!" }

C:\>hello
Don't Panic!
```